# SVG isn't sizing properly in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

I know SVG support in IE is wonky but people have managed to get it working properly from IE9 up.

I'm creating a cinema seat selection type thing - much like the AMC one found here when booking for a movie: https://www.amctheatres.com/movies/focus#31347

However in IE my svg is rendering really small. I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Heres my opening svg code with a couple of its inner bits:

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin" height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0, 0, 440, 380">

    <rect width="440" height="7" style="fill:#333e48;"> <!-- The screen --> 

    <g transform="translate(360, 300)">
        <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="8" class="disabled circle" fill="#c6cacd" data-rowindex="3" data-columnindex="3" data-seatnumber="P18" data-areacategorycode="0000000004" data-areanumber="1"></circle>
    </g>
    ...
```

Comment: [**CSS-Tricks : Scaling SVG**](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/)

Comment: Ah great article. Eventually found the trick in there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I eventually figured it out. using @paulie_D's article mentioned in the comments.

Heres a JSfiddle of it working cross browser: http://jsfiddle.net/91b0L2tg/1/

Heres the original article: https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/

```
.svg-container {
   position: relative; 
   height: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
   padding: 0;
   padding-bottom: 100%; 
}

svg {
    position: absolute; 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    left: 0; 
    top: 0;
}
```

A little work and this can be used.

The reason it wasnt working was because IE requires the container div to have the width set to a fixed width rather than 100%